# finding the row that has the first TD containing the specified time

Tags: jquery

```
<tr class="time"><td>7:00am</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="time"><td>7:30am</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="time"><td>8:00am</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="time"><td>8:30am</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="time"><td>9:00am</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="time"><td>9:30am</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

I have a basic table that I am using as a timetable, and would like to traverse the tds and trs.

What I want to do is to first use the "contains" selector to find the row with the time I want, then when I have the Row, I want to use "Eq" to choose which column.

```
$("tr.time:firstChild:contains('"+mytime+"')");
```

I don't even think that's right.

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-find-table-rows-that-contains-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this...

```
$("tr.time td:first-child:contains('" + mytime + "')")
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Xbagv/).

Comment: thanks. How would I get that tr.time to use EQ or get to the TD next to the one I just selected?

Comment: @Adam You could use `next()`.

Comment: sorry, I meant I want to be able to choose which td to select. so 2 cells next to it or 4.

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure what you mean. You can always do `.siblings().eq(3)`.